# how to resize img in html string dom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my project i have to returnt a contents to content of html in side of modalpopup. i have an image ( as icon). it has a default size. i want to minimaze this image for icon size. but it has still real size. how can i make it height=15px and width =10px. i tried lots of things but does not work.

```
 customtoolbar = Magic.label + '<hr>' + '<table>' +
         '<tr><td><img src="/xxx/images/xxx.png" alt="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" width="12" height="15" /></td><td><a href="#">TEST</a></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td><a href="#">Alt Nodları Göster</a></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td><a href="javascript:Magic.onAddNode()">İlişki Ekle</a></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td><a href="javascript:Magic.onRemoveNode()"">İlişki Sil</a></td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td><a href="javascript:Magic.onUnAttachNode(' + Magic.selectedRelationId + ')">İlişki Kes</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: You said you "tried lots of things" - did you try using the `style` attribute for this, rather than the (deprecated) `width` and `height` attributes? Just trying to narrow down the possibilities here.

Comment: I don't think `width` and `height` are deprecated.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img.  The posted code should work fine, *unless* width or height are set for images in the style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have conflicting css that is setting the height and width. I would recommend using css to set the height and width for this image rather than attributes:

```
<img src="/xxx/images/xxx.png" alt="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block; width:12px; height:15px" />
```

If this doesn't work, try the following:

```
<img src="/xxx/images/xxx.png" alt="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block; width:12px !important; height:15px !important" />
```

Essentially the `!important` flag tells the browser to use this css over anything else that has been defined previously. If this works, it's probably worthwhile revisiting your site css.

As a general rule of thumb, inline css (what you have here attached to the element) should be avoided. All of your styles should reside in a css file where possible as it increase reusability of classes etc. Also you don't have to trawl through lines of html to make changes to styles.

Comment: @Penguen Why did you edit my answer? You've made it worse on several points. For a start the first code example isn't valid because there's no quote after src=. You've also given the image src's 4 full stops; this doesn't make any sense. Why did you change the src of the images? I see the OP changed the src from what was there originally, but you could have at least changed them to be the same. Do you mind fixing my answer? Infact, nevermind, I've rolled it back. Never had to do that before!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your code is conflicting with your css
or else try using this:

```
<style>
    img {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 12px !important;
        height: 15px !important;
    }
</style>
```